# How to get the specific user?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

My code looks like this:

```js
app.get("users/:id", async(req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params
    console.log(req.params)
    const data = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM allusers WHERE userid = $1", [id])
    res.send(data)
})
```

But when I go to `localhost:500/users/1` I get:

> Cannot GET /user/1

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're visiting `/user/1` while your code expects `/users/:id`, e.g. `/users/1`. That's your problem, unless you copied your code/error wrongly.

You can alias the routes if you really want both to work for some reason:

```js
const getUser = async(req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params
    console.log(req.params)
    const data = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM allusers WHERE userid = $1", [id])
    res.send(data)
};
app.get("user/:id", getUser);
app.get("users/:id", getUser);
```

Comment: Still not working, when I visit localhost:5000/users/1 it doesn't event log req.params

Comment: Perhaps you have to use `app.get("/users/:id")`, haven't used Express in a while so I don't remember if a leading slash is required. You'd have seen that in the documentation anyway though.